# Adding items to ListView from .txt file

Tags: c++, listview

I'm making Windows Form C++ project using Visual Studio 2015.
I'm wondering if there is such a possibility of adding items to ListView from a .txt file? The program itself makes a file with some data and I want ListView with those data to pop up after pressing button.
Is this possible? Because at this point I don't even know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

ListView controls have no functionality to load a file directly. You have to write your own code to open the file, read the file data, and create the individual ListView items using the file data as needed.  See [`ListView_InsertItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775038.aspx) or [`CListCtrl::InsertItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b9s12fc.aspx), depending on how you are accessing the ListView:

[List-View Control Overviews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485972.aspx)

[CListCtrl Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx)